# How to find a linq generated Sql query that appear in Sql Server Sloq Query log?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I have some performance problem regarding some of my queries. When I [query Sql Server for a list of slow queries](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2008/12/16/quick-and-dirty-sql-server-slow-query-log/), I find some queries that were generated by Linq-To-Entities.

For example:

```
SELECT 
[Project12].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
[Project12].[OrderDate] AS [OrderDate], 
[Project12].[OrderStatusId] AS [OrderStatusId], 
[Project12].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project12].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Project12].[ClientCode] AS [ClientCode], 
[Project12].[TwoLetterCode] AS [TwoLetterCode], 
[Project12].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Project12].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
[Project12].[Code] AS [Code], 
[Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project12].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project12].[C5] AS [C5]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project11].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
    [Project11].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
    [Project11].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Project11].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 

....
```

I tried to use the differents fields to find where I was querying those fields, but I cannot find where.

What technique can be used to find which Linq query generated some sql?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the DataContext.Log method for Linq to SQL (I believe this will work for Linq to Entities as well): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx

Hook that up with a StreamWriter and you can see what your Linq is doing.  You could then use this log to compare against what you get from a SQL profiler log and see what is doing what exactly to compared the two.

I also prefer to use LinqPad while debugging things in straight SQL.  You can even import DLL's for entity framework directly into it to query off of.

http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: You can't use the DataContext.Log with EF.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a number of techniques that would likely help isolate your LINQ performance issues at [ThinqLinq](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Database-Performance-hints).